# How to add element to next free space in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to add an element to an array without knowing where to add it. E.g. Instead of doing something like this...

```
double[] myArray = new double[10];
myArray[5] = 1.0;
```

I want to be able to just add an element to the next available free space. Is this even possible in java? Sorry if it's a simple question, I'm pretty new to the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, define "free". You can't look for the first zero value; what if you actually *wanted* to store zero as a real value.

The only way is to keep track of where you last inserted:

```
double[] myArray = new double[10];
int nextIndex = 0;

myArray[nextIndex++] = 1234;
... etc

myArray[nextIndex++] = 1.0;
```

Note that this is deliberately simplistic. It does not protect against running off the end of the array etc.

Your better option is to use a *Collection*, like `ArrayList`, which expands automatically
and is easy to add to.

Comment: Ok thank you, I wasn't sure if it was possible due to the scenario you mentioned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays don't have "free space". You can use a "magic value" (e.g. zero, or null depending on the type) to represent empty if you wish. Then you can search through the array looking for  this value:

```
int i = Array.asList(array).indexOf(0.0);
```

A few warnings:

- This will be slow as it requires scanning the array.
- You must be certain that the magic value can't occur as an element that you wish to store in the array.

If you just want a collection that can contain a variable number of elements then don't use an array. For example, you could use an [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and its [`add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29) method to add elements to the end.

Answer (score 1):

This makes far more sense for an array of object references, where `null` clearly means "empty". But let's just assume that for an array of `double`, maybe `0` means "empty". So...

```
int index = -1;
for (int i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        array[i] = 5;
        index = i;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Then `index` points to the element you set, or is `-1` if the array was full.